# Passing along keys with whitespace through GTM AMP Variables

Tags: google-tag-manager, amp-html

I'm trying to pass along the value of "content id" as an AMP variable in GTM. However, I'm having trouble getting it to pick up the value [presumably] due to the whitespace in the key:

```
<amp-analytics config="http://example.com/config.json">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "requests": {
    "pageview": "https://example.com/...
  },
  "vars": {
    "content id": "ABC123",
    "author": "John Smith"
  ...
```

Other keys (e.g. author) successfully return values. I've tried *post%20id* among other combinations, even directly referring to the value as a CD (bypassing GTM variables). Does anyone have any insight into AMP/GTM's handling of AMP Article vars with whitespace?

Comment: you need to show the page; other things might be going on here that cause the problem. short term, try content_id.

Comment: You may want to check the AMP features that enable [variable substitutions](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-form/amp-form.md#variable-substitutions) listed in this [GitHub post](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md). Also, this [blog post](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2016/10/google-tag-manager-giving-mobile.html) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use space in variable name, you can use URL encoded version like this:

```
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
    "content%20id": "ABC123",
    "author": "John Smith"
    }
}
</script>
```

Then in GTM use the same `content%20id` variable.

But of course best way is just use something like `content_id`